# How to use any patchlevel of Ruby with .ruby-version - rbenv/rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rbenv

Both [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#choosing-the-ruby-version) and [RVM](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm) support using a `.ruby-version` file to specify a version of Ruby inside a project folder. I want to define only the version without the patchlevel.

I tried the following to define using any patchlevel of Ruby 1.9.3 but neither worked: `1.9.3` and `1.9.3-p*`

I know about [`rbenv-aliases`](https://github.com/tpope/rbenv-aliases) and [`rvm alias`](http://rvm.io/rubies/alias) but is it possible to do this without them?

Tip for Rails users:

You can add to your Gemfile:

```
ruby '1.9.3'
```

which will raise a warning if you try to run your app with a different version.

Answer (score 5):

### RVM

run:

```
rvm list known
```

it will show most used version like:

```
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p247]
```

which means any of this strings will match `ruby-2.0.0-p247`:

- ruby-2.0.0
- 2.0.0
- 2.0.0-p247

if you need to match any other `2.0.0` like `2.0.0-p195` either use full version `2.0.0-p195` or use `--fuzzy` flag:

```
rvm use --fuzzy .
```

The `.` is for current directory - it will load ruby from current dir.

It is also possible to remember the `--fuzzy` flag with:

```
echo rvm_fuzzy_flag=1 >> ~/.rvmrc
```

### rbenv

From what I know rbenv has strict version matching and you need to specify full directory name into which ruby was installed.

### [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby)

Does fuzzy matching by default and any part of the installed ruby string is matched.

Answer (score 1):

With `rvm` you can use:

```
# in .ruby-version
ruby-1.9.3
```

You need the ruby prefix to specify which interpreter to use.

Comment: It works using rvm version 1.20.5, but I must admit that I don't use rbenv, and therefore haven't tried the above using it. As much as it would be nice if functionality was the same between the two, it's really up to the packages to support the syntax. Maybe an issue should be opened with rbenv?

Comment: @joonyt I see. Well i've tried it with `rbenv`. Yes, maybe I'll open an issue. I've edited your answer so a visitor will see thats rvm specific... if you're okay with it.